# cant use dollar sign ($) in neo4j properties

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I want to run a basic query on my node/express server

```
var params = {
  props : {
    id : 1,
    name : "Peter"
  }
}

var query  = [
  'MERGE (p:Person{id:$props.id})',
  'RETURN n.id as id'
];

...
session.run(query, params)
        .then(function(resp){
...
```

but I'm getting the following error message:

> {    code: 'Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError',   message:
>   'Variable `$props` not defined (line 2, column 8 (offset:
>   28))\n"name : $props.id"\n        ^' }

The docs showed me that it is possible to use the dollar sign and I couldnt find anything about this syntax versioning.

---

ubunut version       : 16.04
neo4j version        : 3.0.6
neo4j driver version : 1.1.0

Comment: You call it `$props` in that query but you called it `props` in the `params` object initializer.

Comment: thats the thing about the syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `$param` syntax is only valid **from Neo4j 3.1**

all the versions before it was `{param}`

Comment: couldnt find the info in the documentation, the website of neo4j is not so clear ... can you tell me where to find that info ?