# How to use parameter in neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The Cypher official documentation seems to be inconsistent and misleading when it comes to assigning parameter values..we have the following examples in the refcard:

```
SET n.property1 = $value1
```

where value1 is a parameter defined

```
{
 "value1": somevalue
}
```

However if you use this SET syntax you get an error value1 not defined. The correct syntax seems to be:

```
SET n.property1 = {value1}
```

also if its a MATCH query the parameter looks like this:

```
  {
     email: someemail
    }
```

note no quotes around email
So if you have a MATCH and SET query with parameters you parameters definition looks like this:

```
{
email: someemail,
"status" : somestatus
}
```

Can someone explain this apparent inconsistency?

EDIT:
This is also an example from the neo4j docs:

using parameter with SET clause:

```
{
  "surname" : "Taylor"
}

MATCH (n { name: 'Andres' })
SET n.surname = $surname
RETURN n
```

This returns surname undefined.

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using? The `$` syntax for params in Cypher was introduced in 3.x

Comment: I am using 3.0.8 and 3.1

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328186/cant-use-dollar-sign-in-neo4j-properties), the `$` syntax is valid from 3.1. Can you show how you are passing the parameters?

Comment: @cybersam you maybe right. I didn't actually run the 3.1 test as yet. So the 3.x according to William would not be correct....It would be 3.1+. for it to work I had to use the {value} which is not stated in the documentation that I saw.....maybe in some other documentation. And what with the different use of quotes("") when assigning values to the parameters?

Comment: Quotation depends, in part, on what language you are using to make your queries. Can you show the code you are using to pass the parameters?

Comment: I am only using Javascript...this is  the param code:                      session
  .run ("MATCH (n:Voter {voterid : {paramVoterid}}) SET n.email= {paramEmail},n.password={paramPassword},n.telephone={paramTelephone},n.dob={paramDob} RETURN n",
       { paramVoterid    : newMember.voterid,
         "paramEmail"    : newMember.email,
         "paramPassword" : newMember.password,
         "paramTelephone": newMember.telephone,
         "paramDob"      : newMember.dob
         
       })

Answer (score 4):

You can set params in neo4j desktop browser using **:params**.

For eg,

1. Execute, `:params {surname: 'Taylor'}`
2. Execute, `MATCH (n { name: 'Andres' }) SET n.surname = $surname RETURN n`

For more info of params, use `:help params`